# Trying to create a alias of a class but getting Named error

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python file Account.py where we have a function to create public and private keys when I am trying to build an aliase of the class to run the code in Account, its showing me an Named error, below are the line which I am trying to execute

import time
from Block import Block
from Blockchain import Blockchain
from Account import Account
alice_account = Account('alice')

below is the account.py snippet where we are building the changes

```
class Account:
# Default balance is 100 if not sent during account creation
# nonce is incremented once every transaction to ensure tx can't be replayed and can be ordered (similar to Ethereum)
# private and public pem strings should be set inside __generate_key_pair
def __init__(self, sender_id, balance=100):
    self._id = sender_id
    self._balance = balance
    self._nonce = 0
    self._private_pem = None
    self._public_pem = None
    self.__generate_key_pair()

def __generate_key_pair(self):
    # Implement key pair generation logic
    # Step1: Genrate the private key 
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
    # Generate the RSA private key and Public_key through code 
    key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    )
    private_key_pass= b"Secrete pass"
    # Convert them to pem format strings and store in the class attributes already defined
    self._private_pem= key.private_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
                                         encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(private_key_pass)
    )
    # you can uncomment the below line if want to check the key 
    #print(self._private_pem.splitlines()[0])

    self._public_pem=key.public_key().public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                                                   format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
    )
    # you can uncomment the below line if want to check the key 
    #print(self._public_pem.splitlines()[0])
    return self._private_pem,self._public_pem
```

Comment: ****************************Error Message ***************** "
NameError: name 'private_key_pass' is not defined "

Comment: Which line generates that error message? It would be helpful to see the complete traceback. If you need to add additional information, it is always better to edit your question rather than leaving a comment.